# HCPMs Offline Sync Error about Order_Details OData service

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-connector

I am getting the following error when attempting to run an offline sync. I am using a simple Fiori app connected to the Northwind OData server:

> Error caused by: [-100024] An error occurred while retrieving or parsing the response for request "https://hcpms-pXXXX.hanatrial.ondemand.com:443/SAMPLE/Order_Details".
>
> Error caused by: Missing message for key 'org.apache.olingo.odata2.api.ep.EntityProviderException.INVALID_PROPERTY_VALUE2'!

I am calling the Orders, Customers and Order_Details services. Orders and Customers work fine, but not Order_Details.

Comment: Did it work before?
Have you changed anything?
Maybe modified data structures?

If you switch to debug mode and click on the corresponding request, do you get a response for this request or just the error message?

I assume, this request works ok, if you call it with Chrome: http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Detailshttp://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Order_Details ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The syncing of Order_Details has never worked. However, Orders and Customers work perfectly. And yes it all works perfectly online.

Comment: It seems that your configuration is wrong somewhere .
Have you verified on HCP the configuration of your destinations?

Comment: As I mentioned several times before, the other objects in the service work fine. Therefore its not a problem with the destination.

Comment: We have tested the Order_Details Northwind service from hcpms and it seemed to work ok.
Therefore I assume the problem might be somewhere in your specific configuration/setup.
Have you doublechecked your metadata.xml  for any typos?

Comment: Hmm.. Yep.. Do you have any documentation on debugging the data store on the device? Can I actually look at the data stored locally?

Comment: In Chrome you can switch to “Developer Tools” and then click on tab “Application”, there you will find “Local Storage”.
In addition to this, the “Diagnostics window” might be helpful, as seen [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/37a34cc084014bcdb1d13e6c0976042a.html)
and [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/6ec18e80b0ce47f290bc2645b0cc86e6.html).

Maybe this [link](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/14/smp3-hcpms-root-cause-analysis-with-server-log) about analyzing the server log is also helpful.